# Где взять базу данных с фильмами?

Tags: база-данных, reactjs, поиск-данных

в рамках обучения решил создать React app типа Онлайн кинотеатра. Стал вопрос, где взять базу данных с фильмами, чтобы их смотреть на своем сайте?

Comment: По моему, для учебного проекта не нужна большая база с фильмами. А сотню - другую фильмов можно качнуть с любого трекера, вместе с описаниями.

Answer (score 1):

Сама база фильмов врядли где-то есть в отрытом доступе. Можно потыркать апи ютуба с фильтром "фильмы" - может что свободное и есть.

А база описаний фильмов хорошая https://www.themoviedb.org/

Answer (score 1):

Очень многие из сайтов предоставляют RSS ленту, /sitemap.xml или /search.txt, из которых парсером можно вытащить заголовок и URL. Естественно прямые ссылки на видеофайлы тебе некто не даст. Но так ты хотя-бы сможешь следить на каком сайте что появилось.